# how to access mongodb using pem file

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to access mongodb on remote server using ssl.  I followed the following tutorial [[link]](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/administration/ssl/).

I don't even know about the password part yet as I use ssh and the pem file without a password all the time.

Regardless, I used the following command:

```
mongod --sslOnNormalPorts <my pem file>
```

and got the following error:

```
Error parsing command line: unknown option sslOnNormalPorts
```

is there a simple way for me to access the remote mongodb database remotely?

**EDIT Based on Comments**

I read this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption--host) and tried the following:

```
mongo --host xx.xx.xxx.xxx/db-name --sslPEMKeyFile pemfileName.pem
```

I got the following error:

```
Error parsing command line: unknown option sslPEMKeyFile
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version are you using? the link you sent is for version 2.2 and the options were changed in later versions

Comment: I think it's 3.0.2, but I'm not exactly sure. At least 3.

Comment: you want to follow these instructions: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/ - you were basically following a tutorial for a version that was released several years before 3.0, things have changed significantly since then

Comment: This is great!  I am, however, still confused.  The db I'm trying to access is on an amazon server, and I frequently access that db using `ssh` in the command line; run simple queries, mongoexport...etc.  I'm now trying to do some more sophisticated queries using python.  So, I'm assuming I need this link (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/) found on the page you posted.  I don't understand, however, how this line `mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/client.pem` will access the server.  There's no server address.  What am I missing?

Comment: that would access the server running on the local host, not a remote server - but that has nothing to do with SSL.  If you use that command on the AWS host (after you ssh in) and it works, then MongoDB is set up correctly, but you will probably need to open security groups appropriately to connect remotely.  The arguments for the mongo shell to connect to remote hosts are `--host` and `--port` and I would recommend reading: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption--host

Comment: @AdamComerford I tried based on your comment and got another error.  Any additional help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command
ssh -i ~/my-aws-key.pem -N -f -L 8000:localhost:27017 ubuntu@ec2-54-252-168-106.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com